# Delphi object over TMapView

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

On Android I have a TMapView in align Client. I want to put a TRectangle over the TMapView. Event if I call

```
Rectangle.BringToFront;
```

I never see it. The MapView stay on top I can't show anything over it.
How to do it anyway ?

Comment: You cannot put an FMX rectangle over the top of TMapView because of "z-order" problems using FMX and native controls. There are a limited number of controls that do support proper z-order when using a ControlType value of Platform, here: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/FireMonkey_Native_Android_Controls. Is it just a plain rectangle you wanted to add, or were you planning on more? I ask because I am working on some controls that could be placed on a TMapView

Comment: Thanks you, I would like to put a layout and two rectangle to switch between plan and satellite view

Comment: @DaveNottage I can't put objects over TMapView, ok. But why I can't do a Screenshot too ? MapView.MakeScreenshot didn't return a bitmap screenshot :( Thanks

Comment: For TMapView you need to use the Snapshot method

Comment: I'm facing the same problem too where when i scroll up the form, the mapview overlapped my header bar on the top. How can I solve it?