# How to add an clickable button on top of a MapView in Delphi FireMonkey?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, android-11, delphi-10.4.2

I need to add a clickable button with a custom image on top of the TMapView, is this possible?

ps: even if I leave the TImage on top of the view, the map overlays it, that is, the button appears quickly until the map rendering overlays it...

edit ps2: There is no code for the example, I simply put a TImage on the Form, either as a child of TMapView, or as a child of TForm, when I test it on android, when opening the app the image appears quickly before the map and then when the map starts to appear it overlays the image...

edit ps3: I don't know if a TImage is the correct way to do this, is this any component to leave on top of the map, that keeps showing up, serving as a button? Just like on Google Maps...

Comment: Please add the Delphi version tag to the question, and also the target platform(s). It would also help to provide a [mre] for us to test with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't show anything on TMapView because of "z-order" problem. I looked for while to find a solution.

See : [Delphi object over TMapView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65775393/delphi-object-over-tmapview)